# Evaluating an integral involving a Gaussian function

Tags: integration

I am stuck on the following integral:

$$I(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}}\right]dx_1\cdots dx_n$$

where $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are arbitrary finite real numbers.  If the integral cannot be evaluated in closed-form, I am wondering if $I(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is a monotonic function of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$.

This is related to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56316/hypothesis-test-on-the-euclidean-length-of-an-unknown-vector) on stats.SE.

Comment: If it's a monotonic function of $\sum a_i^2$, then in particular it takes the same value for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ with $\sum a_i^2=1$, say. Do you have a proof of this (still surprising, to me) weaker property? (Numerical calculations seem to confirm it.)

Comment: @GregMartin I am interested in the converse of your statement: if $I(\mathbf{a})$ takes the same value for all $\mathbf{a}$ with the same norm, then it's a monotonic function of the norm of $\mathbf{a}$. It looks like this holds, per Did's answer. However, I am just wondering how you came up with your statement.  Perhaps there is a way to further simplify Did's answer (I do find that answer very elegant though)...

Comment: My comment is just the observation that a monotonic function of $\sum a_i^2$ is, in particular, a *function* of $\sum a_i^2$ - and therefore must give the same answer no matter on tuples $(a_i)$ for which $\sum a_i^2$ is equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $I(a)=E[\exp(a\cdot X/\|X\|)]$ where $X$ is standard normal in $n$ dimensions. The invariance by rotation of the distribution of $X$ indicates that $X/\|X\|$ is uniform on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ hence $I(a)=E[\exp(a\cdot U)]$ where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $S^{n-1}$.

The distribution of $a\cdot U$ does not change when $a$ is replaced by another vector with the same norm hence $I(a)=E[\exp(\|a\|U_1)]$, where $U_1$ denotes the first coordinate of $U$. The distribution of $U_1$ is characterized by the fact that $U_1=\cos(\Theta)$ where the density of $\Theta$ is proportional to $\sin^{n-2}$ on $[0,\pi]$. Hence, $I(a)=F_n(\|a\|)/F_n(0)$ with
$$
F_n(\alpha)=\int_0^{\pi}\mathrm e^{\alpha\cos(t)}\sin^{n-2}(t)\mathrm dt=\int_{-1}^1\mathrm e^{\alpha x}(1-x^2)^{(n-3)/2}\mathrm dx,
$$
which can be expanded as a series in $\alpha^2$ and probably identified as a special function, since
$$
F_n(\alpha)\propto\sum_{k\geqslant0}\frac{\Gamma(k+n/2)\alpha^{2k}}{\Gamma(2k+1)\Gamma(k+1/2)}.
$$
In particular, there exists some positive coefficients $(i_k)_k$ such that
$$
I(a)=\sum_{k\geqslant0}i_k\,\|a\|^{2k},
$$
hence $a\mapsto I(a)$ is increasing with respect to $\|a\|$ from $I(0)=1$ to $\lim\limits_{\|a\|\to\infty}I(a)=+\infty$..

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I didn't see the dot-product when I wrote down $I(\mathbf{a})$, so what you did was really neat. However, I'd like to clarify some points in the answer: (1) in the second paragraph, the distribution of $a\cdot U$ doesn't change when $a$ is replaced by another vector $a'$ with the same norm because $X$ is rotation-invariant and we can find unitary matrix $R$ such that $a\cdot U=a'RUR^T$. We can also find unitary $S$ such that $SUS^T=U_1$ points in the direction of $a$ and obtain $a\cdot U=\|a\|SUS^T$ Is that correct understanding?

Comment: continuing...  (2) Is the fact that $U_1=\cos(\Theta)$ with density of $\Theta$ proportional to $\sin^{n-2}$  on $[0,\pi]$ well-known? (btw, I assume it's $\sin^{n-2}(\Theta)$) Is there a good source where I can learn more about this?  Also, regarding $F_n(\alpha)$ being identified as a special function, indeed it can be using Eq. 3.284.1 in Grandshteyn&Rychik, p. 348 7th edition (though characterization isn't very useful).

Comment: in my first comment, please ignore $R^T$ and $S^T$, since, obviously, $U$ isn't a matrix... (I'd edit it if I could)  sorry, brainfart.

Comment: Reading your comments after a while, I get the impression you resolved the main problems you had. One minor correction, though: the density of $\Theta$ cannot be proportional to $\sin^{n-2}(\Theta)$ because the density of a random variable is a function defined on the image set of the random variable. What one should say is that the density of $\Theta$ is the function $f$ defined on $[0,\pi]$ by $f(t)=c\sin^{n-2}(t)$, for some positive $c$--that is, exactly what I wrote in my answer. Finally, as regards references, the easiest way might be to check WP on gaussian vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am very comfortable working with the Gaussian vectors; what I don't quite get yet is the math related to hyperspheres, which is where I think the density of $\Theta$ comes from. There is an expression for the area element of the $n$-sphere in the subsection of the WP article on hyperspheres titled "Spherical volume element": $dA=\sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\sin^{n-3}(\phi_2)\ldots\sin(\phi_{n-2}d\phi_1d\phi_2 \ldots d\phi_{n-1}$.  Is this where your $f(t)$ comes from? Why do we take the density of $\phi_1$, as opposed to any of the other angles?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Because $\phi_1$ is the only angle which gives a Cartesian coordinate ($x_1$, as it happens) without relying on another angle. For example $x_2 = r \sin(\phi_1) \cos(\phi_2)$ hence $\phi_2$ alone does not yield $x_2$. Spherical coordinates are not invariant by permutation.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!  I just saw that you updated the answer, it makes complete sense in the context of the problem from which this question came -- I have a question about the sum to which $F(\alpha)$ is proportional.  How did you obtain that?  Is that a brute-force Taylor expansion w.r.t. $\alpha^2$ near 0 (with resulting need to show the interchange of integral and sum) or am I missing something clever (like the dot product you saw)?

Comment: Just that--except that there is no need to show the interchange is valid since once the integral is pulled back to $(0,1)$ using $u(x)=e^{\alpha x}+e^{-\alpha x}$, every term in the expansion of $u(x)$ is positive.

Comment: Aha!  I see it now.  Thanks for a great answer!